# Why does CustomTokenRequestValidator service get executed when grant_type="code"?

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

**Expected behavour**
If the user logged in via your SPA web app, and the app uses grant_type=code it is expected that only "ProfileDataRequestContext" service would get executed.
However it also executes ICustomTokenRequestValidator service, why is that? am I doing something wrong?

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
  //this should be executed only when grant_type=code
}
```

-

```
public class CustomTokenRequestValidatorService : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
 //this should only be executed when grant_type=clientcredentials (however it always gets executed at all times)
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it'd only be for `client_credentials`? I believe that'd be executed for all `token` endpoint requests just like `ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator` is executed for all `authorize` endpoint requests.

Comment: I thought IProfileService is for user token only and CustomTokenRequestValidationContext is for access token? Is that right? I just realized the SPA web app gets two tokens one user id token and the other access token. that's why it executes twice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the flow, [described by the spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps), you could see that `code flow` consists of at least two calls to `Authorization Server`, and the second one is the call to `Token Endpoint`, triggering the `TokenRequestValidator` invocation, as well as each call to the `AuthorizationEndpoint` triggers the `AuthorizeRequestValidator` correspondingly.

For SPA and native apps that does not matter, but for MVC apps the context of the calls to `Authorization` and `Token` endpoints differs a lot: the first one is performed in the context of the browser, so contains some browser-specific headers, such as locale, when the second one is a server-to-server (back channel) call.

Regarding your sub-question about IProfileService invocation: that takes place each time the token or response contains `UserClaims`. When you request `id_token`, `access_token` and then retrieve some additional data from `UserInfo` endpoint, your `IProfileService` might be called three times.

Comment: I thought profileservice is only called when id_token is required, to get the user info only? is IProfileService is for user token and CustomTokenRequestValidationContext is for access token?

Comment: RequestValidators as well as their contexts are constantly bound to their endpoints, not token types. you can get both tokens from `AuthorizationEndpoint` (implicit flow), both from `TokenEndpoint` (code flow) and mix that (hybrid). that invokes validators differently. and `IProfileService` -- that's just about fetching user claims, any token could require that: `id_token` obligatorily and `access_token` -- optionally

Answer (score 1):

`ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator` is called for every grant type as per the [source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/d942a4fc80a36f97e5765dd6175c79a2f370db3d/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/TokenRequestValidator.cs#L161). Having said that, you get `CustomTokenRequestValidationContext` passed into the `ValidateAsync` which has `TokenRequestValidationResult` which has `ValidatedTokenRequest` which in turn has `GrantType` property so if you aim to only run some code on client credentials - a simple if statement should suffice:

```
public async Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
{
    if (context.Result.ValidatedRequest.GrantType == "client_credentials")
    {
    ...your logic
    }
}
```